# ResourceFilterFactory and non-Path annotated Resources

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jersey-1.0

(I'm using Jersey 1.7)

I am attempting to add a ResourceFilterFactory in my project to select which filters are used per method using annotations.

The ResourceFilterFactory seems to be able to filters on Resources which are annotated with the Path annotation but it would seem that it does not attempt to generate filters for the methods of the SubResourceLocator of the resources that are called.

```
@Path("a")    
public class A {

 //sub resource locator?
 @Path("b")
 public B getB() { 
   return new B();
 }

 @GET
 public void doGet() {}
}

public class B {
 @GET
 public void doOtherGet() { }

 @Path("c")
 public void doInner() { }
}
```

When ran, the Filter factory will only be called for the following:
AbstractResourceMethod(A#doGet)
AbstractSubResourceLocator(A#getB)

When I expected it to be called for every method of the sub resource.

I'm currently using the following options in my web.xml;

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>com.my.MyResourceFilterFactory</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
     <param-value>com.my.resources</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Is my understanding of the filter factory flawed?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use @Path annotation at class level for Class B. When Jersey does the resource scan I bet you that it doesnt pick up this class as a resource.

Comment: It does, i've been running this class setup for quite a bit and i've only hit a problem with it using the ResourceFilterFactory. The only difference between the example and my code is that the subclasses are annotated with a @Produces.

Comment: The fact that you got it to work before, is very strange to me. Before implementing ResourceFilterFactory, what URL were you using to hit the subresource "doOtherGet()" defined in class B?

Comment: that would be GET on /a/b. Like I said previously, i've been running this setup on multiple developement machines and in production for about a year.

Comment: You are right, I didn't see the line of code where you create a new instance of class B. Here is my understanding of the situation: Since you are not assigning a path to your class B, it is not officially registered with Jersey, but you are handling the situation by manually mapping the requestes to your desired subResource. To filter the requests or responses, you have two main options: (1) implementing a resourceFilterFactory, (2) registering implementations of ContainerRequestFilter & ContainerResponseFilter. You are using the first approach -->

Comment: In the first approach (the one you are using right now), as soon as the application  starts Jersey scans all the resources that all EXPLICITLY defined (i.e. with the 'Path' at class level) and extracts their subResources (Abstract Methods) and then creates a different filters for each subresource. In your case, I don't think Jersey can see that class as a resource without the 'Path' annotation when the filters are created.

Comment: Since I originally created the question, I have tought a bit about why this behavior would not make sense and since sub resource locators could return different implementation of a resource depending on any factor (I could decided to return any subclass of B in that example) it can't scan that resource.

I'm currently using Servlet filters but I don't think I could use them for my particular problem.

Comment: Just run into this issue, does anyone found a workaround within jersey 1?